# Xcode 8 hangs up on loading

Tags: crash, xcode8, freeze

Whenever I try to open a project in Xcode, it gets stuck on loading and never finishes. Xcode eventually stops responding, and I have to force quit. This happens to all my projects and seemed to happen all of a sudden after restarting my macbook.

I have tried to delete and install Xcode, delete the entire developer file in library, as well as delete the data files in the package contents.

update: The problem went away and came back after a few days of doing nothing. very strange problem

[image]

Comment: There are several possible causes. This might help you: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/86094/xcode-hangs-at-startup

Comment: The only way I can fixed it was by removing project.xcworkspace folder inside the project.xcodeproj package. I try all other solution posted here and them did not work for Xcode 8

Answer (score 17):

I was in similar situation and one of the above comments helped me narrow it down.

If the code is in your iCloud folder and happens to be waiting to upload to iCloud for some reason (6MB waiting, seemed stuck), kill Xcode, turn Wi-Fi off for a second, reopen your project, and it should open right up.  You can then resume using Wi-Fi.

Moving the code out of your iCloud managed folder would probably help.

Answer (score 11):

Try

Remove `~/Library/Development/`

Remove `~/Library/Caches`

Remove `~/Library/Autosave Information`

It works to me on same issue

**Edited**

If you use Sierra with Xcode8 and your project in iCloud Documents

move project to another directory not in iCloud

it should cause problem

Comment: the true reason! thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your Xcode project shouldn't be in an iCloud Drive folder.

Comment: Hi. I was just wondering why that is. I couldn't find the reason online. (Side note: this happened to me which is why I stumbled upon this. Moving out of iCloud Drive fixed my issue, but I was just wondering why iCloud Drive causes this)

Comment: Because iCloud Drive sends the data to the cloud and sometimes remove local copies. When you try to access it it is downloaded back from iCloud.
That is why you have the cloud icon next to the name of the file.
Considering the number of files you can have in a project if you have to download each class to compile it will take forever.

Answer (score 2):

My problem was due to iCloud.
All my projects were inside documents folder which is iCloud folder.
Because iCloud settings in my MacBook was with the optimize option, the content of files weren’t allocated locally in the hard drive but remotely in iCloud. That was the cause for unresponsiveness of Xcode when loading the project or even starting new one.
I moved all the projects to local folder in hard disk not included as a backup for iCloud and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if your application be using camera and photo, try remove and reopen storyboard.

After I create a new project and copy/paste  item by item (scene), I found the bug. in my case, the Camera and Photo using tag . So, I removed row, and open as interface building. and... Worked again!

so, I just need recreate the views again.. Sry my English!

Answer (score 0):

Try these simple Steps, works for me:-

1. Go to file, then Workspace Settings
2. Tap of next arrow button above advance button [![enter image description here][1]][1]

   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMyTs.png
3. Delete all data in derived folder.
4. Quit your Xcode and now open project again.

Cheers!!
Happy Coding !!!

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the above and nothing worked for me, until I realised that my project was inside an iCloud backed folder. After I removed it then things started to work again. What a stupid mistake!!

Hope this helps someone out there.